# Emails displaying text in uppercase in Outlook on Mac

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, css

I am testing out Marketing Cloud and have come across an issue in my test emails in Outlook where the text is displaying in uppercase. This issue only appears to be happening on my Apple Mac. I have tested this in Gmail on mobile and desktop and all appears fine. Any ideas on how I can edit the Global Styles or fix this issue? For reference, I have used the blank email template in Marketing Cloud.

Comment: Please provide further information: What version of Outlook are you using? What text is appearing in uppercase? Share your code and HTML markup.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. in which my whole email content (email sent from application as html) gets 'All Caps Text'.. Outlook version - 2016, Desktop Mac, Windows